# Groupby and sum last rows with dplyr

Tags: r

Suppose I have  the following 'companies' dataset:

```
Company      Revenue  
Pepsi          10      
Pepsi          20    
Pepsi          30     
Pepsi          10       
Fanta          10       
Fanta          70        
Fanta          90      
Fanta          80     
Fanta          20       
Fanta          40
```

I want to find the sum of the last two rows for each company, i.e. I want the following output:

```
Company       Sum 
Pepsi         40      
Fanta         60
```

where 40 = 20 +10, and 60 = 20 + 40

I try to group by company, but I do not know how to get only the last two rows:

```
data %>%
group(Company) %>%
summarise(Sum = sum(revenue))
```

do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tail(Revenue, 2)` would give you last two values of `Revenue`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Company) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(tail(Revenue, 2)))

#  Company Revenue
#  <chr>     <int>
#1 Fanta        60
#2 Pepsi        40
```

You may also use indexing -

```
df %>% group_by(Company) %>% summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue[(n()-1):n()]))
```

---

The logic can also be implemented in base R and `data.table`

```
#Base R
aggregate(Revenue~Company, df, function(x) sum(tail(x, 2)))

#data.table

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Revenue = sum(tail(Revenue, 2))),Company]
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `slice_tail` after grouping by 'Company'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Company) %>%
     slice_tail(n = 2) %>%
     summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `last()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(last(Revenue, 2)))
```

```
  Company   Sum
  <chr>   <int>
1 Fanta      60
2 Pepsi      40
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `slice` here:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Company) %>% 
  slice((n()-1):n()) %>% 
  summarize(Revenue = sum(Revenue))
```